# How can I get Mono 2.11+ installed on Travis-CI?

Tags: mono, travis-ci

I build my C# project on Travis-CI [like this](https://github.com/JayBazuzi/Pash2/blob/e748f1ee54751b85e7a5a0e62f6a20ac6f93170a/.travis.yml):

```
# .travis.yml
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq mono-devel gtk-sharp2

install:
  - xbuild Source/Pash.sln
```

Travis uses Precise (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) which seems like a good choice for them, but it includes Mono 12.10. My C# project hits a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6541) in Mono 2.10. The bug appears to be fixed in Mono 2.11+.

I read that Ubuntu is slow to pick up new builds of Mono because so much depends on it, and it can break so much. That's fine, but for Travis dependencies aren't really a problem - the machine goes away at the end of the build!

I have considered

- compiling a new Mono in `.travis.yml` but I don't want to put that much burden on the Travis servers.
- Building a MCS (Mono C# compiler) with just this fix.
- Downloading and installing a newer Mono from somewhere (where?)
- Checking a recent Mono in to my GIT repo.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use something higher than what standard distro packages provide, I recommend you to go all the way and not use unstable 2.11.x series, but official/beta 3.x ones.

So, grab yourself some preview Debian/Ubuntu 3.0.6 packages from this PPA:

http://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to get a full up to date mono environment is to use an OS X travis profile

```
language: objective-c

before_install:
 # Make sure mono is installed,
 - wget http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.0.10/macos-10-x86/MonoFramework-MDK-3.0.10.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg
 - hdid MonoFramework-MDK-3.0.10.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg
 - sudo installer -pkg "/Volumes/Mono Framework MDK 3.0.10/MonoFramework-MDK-3.0.10.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg" -target /

install:
 - xbuild Source/Pash.sln
```